# ZXing on the second tab keep scanning and disturb first tab events

Tags: java, android, zxing

I use tablayout and viewpager to display 2 feature, first tab there's a button to check either the serial number in barcode is valid or not then if the number is also valid it will execute top up process and the second tab is just to check if the serial number is already used or not. The problem is, when the activity is running and I click nothing but the scanner from second tab is always scanning if there is a barcode close to the camera

I try to add condition when second tab is clicked then I execute what's in second tab process do it is checking either serial number is valid or not but it doesn't work.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle state) {
    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getActivity());

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(VmRegistrasiSp.class);
    if(state != null) {
        mFlash = state.getBoolean(FLASH_STATE, false);
        mAutoFocus = state.getBoolean(AUTO_FOCUS_STATE, true);
        mSelectedIndices = state.getIntegerArrayList(SELECTED_FORMATS);
        mCameraId = state.getInt(CAMERA_ID, -1);
        statusCam = false;
    } else {
        mFlash = false;
        mAutoFocus = true;
        mSelectedIndices = null;
        mCameraId = -1;
        statusCam = true;
    }
    setupFormats();
    return mScannerView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    MenuItem menuItem;

    if(mFlash) {
        menuItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.menu_flash, 0, R.string.flash_on);
    } else {
        menuItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.menu_flash, 0, R.string.flash_off);
    }
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menuItem, MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);


    if(mAutoFocus) {
        menuItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.menu_auto_focus, 0, R.string.auto_focus_on);
    } else {
        menuItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.menu_auto_focus, 0, R.string.auto_focus_off);
    }
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menuItem, MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);

    menuItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.menu_formats, 0, R.string.formats);
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menuItem, MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);

    menuItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.menu_camera_selector, 0, R.string.select_camera);
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menuItem, MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_flash:
            mFlash = !mFlash;
            if(mFlash) {
                item.setTitle(R.string.flash_on);
            } else {
                item.setTitle(R.string.flash_off);
            }
            mScannerView.setFlash(mFlash);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_auto_focus:
            mAutoFocus = !mAutoFocus;
            if(mAutoFocus) {
                item.setTitle(R.string.auto_focus_on);
            } else {
                item.setTitle(R.string.auto_focus_off);
            }
            mScannerView.setAutoFocus(mAutoFocus);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_formats:
            DialogFragment fragment = FormatSelectorDialogFragment.newInstance(this, mSelectedIndices);
            fragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "format_selector");
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_camera_selector:
            mScannerView.stopCamera();
            DialogFragment cFragment = CameraSelectorDialogFragment.newInstance(this, mCameraId);
            cFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "camera_selector");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    mScannerView.startCamera();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(FLASH_STATE, mFlash);
    outState.putBoolean(AUTO_FOCUS_STATE, mAutoFocus);
    outState.putIntegerArrayList(SELECTED_FORMATS, mSelectedIndices);
    outState.putInt(CAMERA_ID, mCameraId);
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    try {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getApplicationContext(), notification);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {}

    Intent sendData = new Intent(getActivity(), ActRegistrasVoucher.class);
    sendData.putExtra("dataBarcodeCheck",rawResult.getText());
    sendData.putExtra("flagPager", 2);
    startActivity(sendData);
    Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).finish();
}

public void closeMessageDialog() {
    closeDialog("scan_results");
}

public void closeFormatsDialog() {
    closeDialog("format_selector");
}

public void closeDialog(String dialogName) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    DialogFragment fragment = (DialogFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(dialogName);
    if(fragment != null) {
        fragment.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
    // Resume the camera
    mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
}

@Override
public void onFormatsSaved(ArrayList<Integer> selectedIndices) {
    mSelectedIndices = selectedIndices;
    setupFormats();
}

@Override
public void onCameraSelected(int cameraId) {
    mCameraId = cameraId;
    mScannerView.startCamera(mCameraId);
    mScannerView.setFlash(mFlash);
    mScannerView.setAutoFocus(mAutoFocus);
}

public void setupFormats() {
    if(statusCam){
        mScannerView.stopCamera();
    }else {
        List<BarcodeFormat> formats = new ArrayList<BarcodeFormat>();
        if (mSelectedIndices == null || mSelectedIndices.isEmpty()) {
            mSelectedIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int i = 0; i < ZXingScannerView.ALL_FORMATS.size(); i++) {
                mSelectedIndices.add(i);
            }
        }

        for (int index : mSelectedIndices) {
            formats.add(ZXingScannerView.ALL_FORMATS.get(index));
        }

        if (mScannerView != null) {
            mScannerView.setFormats(formats);
        }
    }
}
```

There is no error messages but the process doesn't resulting desired output. I expect that barcode scanner in second tab only work when the tab is active

Comment: The `ViewPager` keeps the two fragments next to the active fragment resumed. Therefore your camera handling with `onResume` and `onPause` does not work. You could add a listener to the `ViewPager` to manually signal that the fragment should start or stop scanning.

Comment: @Jannik so, you suggest to add onitemclicklistener to the ViewPager in activity?

Comment: I would use the `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` which has the function `onPageSelected(int position)`. Or if you use a `TabLayout` you could add a ÒnTabSelectedListener`.

Comment: @Jannik Already used it but still resulting same result

Comment: In your code above you call `ScannerView.startCamera()` and `stopCamera()` in `onResume` and `onPause`. What I meant is to replace these calls by manually calling these functions from the listener when appropriate, i.e. when the fragment is selected you would call `startCamera` and when the fragment is deselected you call `stopCamera`.

Comment: @Jannik I add adapter.getItem(position).onResume() or adapter.getItem(position).onPause() in onPageSelected and the app crashed, please help

Comment: You shoudn't call the lifecycle callbacks yourself. Instead you would create two new functions to enable and disable the camera.